# How to measure the time of a Maya script?

Tags: performance, maya, mel

I have several methods implemented in MEL, and I would like to measure its performance. Is there any way to measure execution time of a fragment of code? Something equivalent to "getCurrentTime" in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `timerX()` command will give you seconds since Maya was started, so you can grab that and do the math:

```
float $start = timerX();
```

Comment: One may want to avoid evaling the timer!

Comment: I cannot get TimerX to work in backticks in 2015.  I dont' do much mel if I can avoid it, but I I think it's something non-standard

Comment: mel does not need back ticks its just syntax sugar, you can always write commands in c call form

Answer (score 1):

Timer

```
// Example 1: Simple timing
//
$startTime = `timerX`;
// code that is being timed
$totalTime = `timerX -startTime $startTime`;
print ("Total Time: "+$totalTime+"\n");
```